# Control keyboard input in Java

Tags: java

I have this program to write and have no idea how to control keyboard input:

> Write a method to check whether the word entered is valid or not.
>   Valid word should:
>
> 1. Have at least 10 characters
> 2. Start with a letter
> 3. Contain a letter in upper case
> 4. Contain at least 3 digits
> 5. Contain a special character (e.g. @,$.%   …etc)
> 6. Contain a space

Comment: This isn't asking you to control keyboard, but to write a method that validates a String

Comment: You should take a look at `String` methods like `charAt`, `length`. Also some methods from `Character` class can be useful. If you want you can also write regex for that, but that could be an overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
String REGEX = "(^[a-zA-Z](?=.*\\d{3,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%])(?=\\s+).{10,})";
String INPUT = "your password";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(INPUT);
System.out.println("matches(): "+matcher.matches());


^[a-zA-Z]           # Start with a letter
(?=.*\\d{3,})       # at least three digits must occur
(?=.*[a-z])         # a lower case letter must occur at least once
(?=.*[A-Z])         # an upper case letter must occur at least once
(?=.*[@#$%])        # a special character must occur at least once
(?=\\s+)            # a space must occur at least once
.{10,}              # anything, at least ten places though
$                   # end-of-string
```

To use this, read your password (from file,swing elements,...) and call a method, say `validate(String pass)`, inside `validate` check it against the regex.

Comment: If you solve homework, you should do it right. The task is to write a method! ;)

Comment: @Absurd-Mind haha, I think that is the easy part. Nevertheless, I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to validate it on every key stroke, wait till the user has entered the word, then validate. Assuming you are using console input:

```
System.out.print("Enter something > ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String inputString = input.nextLine();

//perform validations on inputString, heres the first one:
//regex could be used instead of multiple if statements
if(inputString.length() < 10) {
    System.out.println("Validation failed, word was too short");
}
else if ...
```

Comment: not yet, you need to click the tick underneath the arrows

Comment: one more question if possible >>>> is there a method to check if there as an upper case in the word ?

Comment: @user3019158 that would be a good use of [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex).

Comment: As @ajb has said, regular expressions are useful for this. You can also use the technique described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127923/java-checking-letter-case-upper-lower-within-a-string-homework-looking-for)

Answer (score -1):

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Number");
```

//in here "input" is a Scanner name you can use any name for it as OBAMA.

```
int x=input.nextInt();
```

//here you can assigne the key board value for "x".

```
System.out.println(x);
```

then you can print it.