# Tell if string contains a-z chars

Tags: java, string, contains

I very new to programming. I want to check if a string s contains a-z characters. I use:

```
if(s.contains("a") || s.contains("b") || ... {
}
```

but is there any way for this to be done in shorter code? Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean contains *at least one* character in the range a-z, or contains *only* characters in the range a-z?

Comment: I believe he means `contains("a")` which would mean at least one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127923/checking-letter-case-upper-lower-within-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use regular expressions

```
// to emulate contains, [a-z] will fail on more than one character, 
// so you must add .* on both sides.
if (s.matches(".*[a-z].*")) { 
    // Do something
}
```

this will check if the string contains at least one character a-z

to check if all characters are a-z use:

```
if ( ! s.matches(".*[^a-z].*") ) { 
    // Do something
}
```

for more information on regular expressions in java

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Just a clarification: This regex checks if a string contains a-z characters lowercase, if all the alphabetical characters are uppercase, like "STACK20", it'll return false.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to regular expressions, and assuming you actually want to know if the String doesn't contain only characters, you can use [Character.isLetter(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) -

```
boolean hasNonLetters = false;
for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
  if (!Character.isLetter(ch)) {
    hasNonLetters = true;
    break;
  }
}
// hasNonLetters is true only if the String contains something that isn't a letter -
```

From the Javadoc for `Character.isLetter(char)`,

> A character is considered to be a letter if its general category type, provided by `Character.getType(ch)`, is any of the following:
>
> ```
> UPPERCASE_LETTER
> LOWERCASE_LETTER
> TITLECASE_LETTER
> MODIFIER_LETTER
> OTHER_LETTER
> ```

Comment: Character class has many useful is...() thx!

Answer (score 2):

Use Regular Expressions. The [Pattern.matches()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method can do this easily. For example:

```
Pattern.matches("[a-z]", "TESTING STRING a");
```

If you need to check a great number of string this class can be compiled internally to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
if (p.matcher(stringToMatch).find()) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75612210/7126848