# Compare two strings in java, one is uppercase and the other is lowercase?

Tags: java

I want to compare two strings. When one is uppercase and other is lower case. How to verify that var1 is uppercase and var2 is lowercase using java string comparison method?

```
 String var1 = "HELLOWORLD";
 String var2 = "helloworld";
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127946/13608717

Comment: Yes, I need to use Character.toUpperClass() to verify if var1 texts are all upper case. I appreciate you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see this solution you can try it.

```
String var1 = "HELLOWORLD";
String var2 = "helloworld";
if(var1.toUpperCase().equals(var2){
System.Out.Print("test success");
}
else{
System.Out.Print("test failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [equalsIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) from the Strings library:

```
if (var1.equalsIgnoreCase(var2)) {
  // do stuff
}
```